# android - onActivityResult() is not invoked when i used it in the tabs (zxing scanner)

Tags: android, zxing, android-tabs

I used **zxing scanner** for scanning the barcodes and QR codes because it is open source. It is working fine except in tabs means I used the same code in the tab group but here it's not working. The problem is onActivityResult() is not invoked. How can we solve this issue.

```
code
```

**SubActivity**

```
public class ScannScreenActivity extends Activity 
{  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.scan, null);
        this.setContentView(viewToLoad);

         mShowCamBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ScannScreenActivity.this);
                     integrator.initiateScan();                 
                }                                             
            });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
          IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
          if (scanResult != null)
          {

              System.out.println("ScannScreenActivity FormatName:"+scanResult.getFormatName());
              System.out.println("ScannScreenActivity Content:"+scanResult.getContents());
          }       
    }
}
```

**ActivityGroup**

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup 
{
   //......
  ........Some code

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {

      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
      {       
          ScannScreenActivity activity = (ScannScreenActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
          activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
  }
}
```

**Log**

```
09-21 11:45:32.448: D/memalloc(10723): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5239b000 size:8560640 offset:7024640
09-21 11:45:32.458: D/memalloc(10723): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51f79000 size:4280320 offset:2744320
09-21 11:45:33.949: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10723): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-21 11:45:33.999: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10723): InputConnection = android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection@40dc2da0, active client = false
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several "flavors" of the `IntentIntegrator` class supplied with the zxing project. You should use `IntentIntegrator` rather than write your own code. And, you need to use the right version. Try `IntentIntegratorV30` which lets you send the result to a fragment rather than the main activity. I believe this is the essence of what you need, since you are really using fragments, right?

Comment: No. Here i am using TabActivity. is any problem with this?

Answer (score -1):

```
ScannScreenActivity activity = (ScannScreenActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity(); 
activity.setResult(resultCode, data);
```

Comment: also chk whether u used startActivity or startActivityForResult

Comment: Here i used the Zxing ScanningViaIntent. I think it's internally uses startActivityForResult() right?

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to scan QR-code.source I used like this. mudah2an can help.

```
private void startScanner() {

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Class1.this, CaptureActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intents.Scan.ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int p_requestCode, int p_resultCode, Intent p_data) {
    try {
        switch (p_requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (p_resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   System.out.println(p_data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Scan Failed")
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        E.handle(this, e);
    } catch (Error e){
        E.handle(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge whenever you start an activity for result it invokes the onActivityResult() for Example:

```
startActivityForResult(intent,KEY);
```

then in onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){    
    switch(requestCode){
    case KEY:
        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)  
            *do whatever you want to *
        }
}
```

Comment: i am sorry but i am not familiar with the tab group, could you please let me know what exactly is the importance of the same.